# Python command working even after deleting from environment variable PATH

Tags: python

[image]

Python command works in a command prompt opened before deleting its path(*C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310*) in the PATH environment variable but does not work in a command prompt opened after deleting it from the environment variable.
Could someone explain why this happens ?
My initial thoughts: The Path Variable gets cached as soon as a new command prompt is opened and the same is used thereafter.

Comment: You initial thoughts are correct.  Each terminal is a process and the variables it stores are stored in RAM. So it is cached. And it will use the old value unless the variables are refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the python path to `C:\Program Files\Python310`

Or reinstall.